# Access video outside the public web dir

Tags: php, html, video

To avoid access to some video mp4 files by http I stored them outside the web public folder. I have access by $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ... to those files. 
The html5 file now tries to access the video by the video src tag with a correct path.

The access works fine for non video files, however videos do not work.

Streaming problem? Any ideas?
Thank you very much

Comment: "The access works fine for non video files, however videos do not work." I really don't think that's the case unless you've taken other steps you're not describing.

Comment: what happens? do you have correct MIME types set for the video files?

Comment: We just have the html page holding -beside other content- this video element. The element is not more than the video tag under HTML 5. If the video file is in the same folder, there is no problem. The path to the video file outside the public web is fine because I tested it with an include.

Comment: PHP includes work because they're processed **server-side** and the server has access to those files. You can't use a file outside the web public folder on the client-side.